# Codeigniter view file looping query

Tags: codeigniter, loops, view, foreach, group-by

Right, I'm unsure about how to code my view file to generate following query results WITHOUT compromising the principles of mvc.

Query in model:

```
SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY country, area ORDER BY country, area
```

View:

```
<?php if (isset($query)):?>
<?php foreach ($query as $row):?>
<h2><?=$row->country?></h2>
<h3><?=$row->area?></h3>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I want the results to display:

England
North
South
West - utilising the GROUP BY parameter

As opposed to:

England
North
England
South
England
West

Has anybody any advice as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve (you should probably show some structure of data in database), but I can give you some advice.

First, since you are using CI, you should use existing CodeIgniter query functions instead of directly writing queries. You may find a list of these functions [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). Also, you need to make a Controller with some function that will accept the data from Model and pass it on in an array to the View.